# Как сделать проверку того, что объект уже соприкоснулся с другим объектом?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я не знаю как сделать проверку того, что объект соприкоснулся с другим объектом, и больше очки не должны засчитываться с тем объектом

Comment: Добрый день. Посмотрите по ссылке официальную справку: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collision-collider.html

Comment: Покажите код проверки соприкосновения? Например, если Вы делаете это по тэгу, то можно просто менять тэг у объекта, к которому Вы прикоснулись.